# Differential Equation and subspace of solution

Tags: differential

Show that the solutions of the homogeneous linear ODE $$\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = 0$$ on an interval I = [a,b] forms a vector subspace W of the real vector space of continuous function on I. What is the dimension of W?

The ode looks simple (if so) but how to go about the second part? And also, what's the significance of "homogeneous" being given?

Comment: Any clues on this one guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the significance of being homogeneous is that the origin( zero function witch is $y(x)=0$) is in the space formed by solutions of ODE witch is a property of Vector Spaces.

also the solution of ODE is as follow:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y}=-p(x)dx \Rightarrow lny=-\int p(x)dx +Constant \Rightarrow y=Ae^{-\int p(x)dx}$$

what I get from Problem is that we must show the solution is a Vector Subspace on Real Numbers which mean Scalars come from $\mathbb R$.

1- ODE is Homogeneous so zero vector is in solution space apparently.

2-if $y_1=A_1e^{-\int p(x)dx}$ and $y_2=A_2e^{-\int p(x)dx}$ and $c$ is a scalar(a real number in this case) then $y_1+cy_2=(A_1+cA_2)e^{-\int p(x)dx}$ is a solution too. so we are dealing with a vector subspace of the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$.

Also dimension of the subspace is one because the only member of the set $\{e^{-\int p(x)dx} \} $ spans the whole space.

Comment: Oh I was pointlessly complicating it then. Thanks :) I see now it's more of a question from vector space than differential equation. Silly!

Comment: maybe I'm thinking too simple  .____.' . is it reasonable to you?

Comment: It is. It actually is a simple question, I was complicating it in my head.

Comment: thanks. that was a comfort, I'm still on wheels :D. good luck with ODE's